# Match jetty url-pattern to only root directory

Tags: web-applications, servlets, passwords, jetty, cometd

I would like to only password protect the root directory on my context path for a Jetty WebApp. My context path is /MyApp, so I would like to require a password for accessing:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp
```

But NOT for:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/cometd
```

My current set up is below (pay attention to the url-pattern):

```
<security-constraint>   
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Private Page</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>moderator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I would expect this to work just by nature of how / and /* work in general. I've also seen this resource which I believe is suggesting that this should pretty much work: http://www.coderanch.com/t/364782/Servlets/java/there-key-difference-between-url

However, for my case, the url patterns:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

and

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

seem to be acting the exact same: both

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/cometd
```

are BOTH password protected.

Of course, if I change to /nothingishere, just as a sanity test, nothing is password protected, except for /MyApp/nothingishere

Does anyone know how to only protect the root directory for web servlets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>   
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Private Page</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>moderator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>   
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Public page</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>        
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

In this configuration, the root directory is password protected and the `/test/...` directory is not. I think this is what you are asking for.

This configuration is tested on Tomcat 7+ and a new project created from the beginning in NetBeans (I can email you the whole source if you need it).

This is the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Works for me as well :) I'll award bounty as soon as the 24 hours are up.

Comment: of course this answer in not only for jetty but all j2ee compliant web-servers. So you might want to change the heading... Btw, glad i helped

Comment: Is there a way that does not require white listing all sub-paths?

Comment: i.e. Having all sub-paths be unprotected with having to add a security constraint for them one by one.