# Web.xml security constraint on context-root doesn't apply

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, web.xml, security-constraint

I have a java webapp that uses web.xml to configure its security:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>webPages</web-resource-name>
        <description>All web resources</description>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admins</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>SSL not required</description>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I want all pages under /admin/* to be protected, and this works. the user correctly first sees a loginscreen, and is redirected afterwards to the original requested page.

I would also like my context root to protected: http://host:port/context/ However, when I configure the pattern `<url-pattern></url-pattern>` and make a request to the root, my java controller just starts working and shows the view without the user ever seeing the login screen. Why does this pattern work for things like `<servlet-mapping>` (to map the request to the spring servlet) but not as a security constraint?

I ttried in both chrome and firefox and restarted multiple times.

Comment: Did you use /* for your root context configuration?

Comment: @aksappy No, because /* as a url pattern means "catch all requests", i do not want that, only the root context. For example, /otherpage.do should keep working without authorization.

Comment: As per the specification, what you have done is right.

Answer (score 0):

You could try white-list approach, it means giving access for public resource only.

[Here is a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509716/match-jetty-url-pattern-to-only-root-directory) with example, but in your case should be something like this:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>webPages</web-resource-name>
    <description>All web resources</description>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admins</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <description>SSL not required</description>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>   
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Public Resources</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/alsopublic</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>...an so on...</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>  
  <!-- to given public access don't set auth-constraint-->
</security-constraint>
```

Edit:
Ref to [servlet 3 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf)

Comment: This doesn't work. The server correctly knows that the root is now "secured", but when it tries to redirect to the loginpage, located at /login.do, I think this request gets blocked to. After a few seconds I get an error message on the server saying the maximum amount of threads has been created, which indicates an infinite loop. Also, the your link to the servlet 3 specs doesn't work for me: I'm not authorized to perform that request it seems.

Comment: I don't understand your comment:  ¿<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> secure the root only like it should?. Also specify what /login.do does after login the user (eg. which redirects).

Comment: by declaring /, It also secures all my other content, not just the root. I think that's / is not the proper way to describe the context root. According to servlet 3.0, the correct url pattern is the empty string.